hapi.js/joi - How to validate boolean query parameter
Consider a url such as http://api.example.com/query?includeDisabled.  How would one construct a Joi validation schema in hapi.js to validate that the 'includeDisabled' query parameter has been provided and should have a value of 'true', without resorting to changing the query string to ?includeDisabled=true?
I'd rather not have to add =true to the query string, but I'm struggling to get Joi to validate it and apply a default value of 'true'.

Since you only have the key and no value, have you tried validating against empty and setting the default value to true? It must be a string though: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.12.3#string
